# How to prevent Ubuntu installer from connecting to Canonical

Tags: server, debian-installer, kickstart

To be precise, I created PXE kickstart installation from ubuntu-15.10-server-amd64.iso with virt-install. After network detections it hangs for a long time trying to connect to Canonical server (which I checked with tcpdump)

I used kernel and initrd from ISO image directory install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz and kernel from install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux

```
$ sudo tcpdump -ni virbr1
listening on virbr1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:45:13.795894 IP 192.168.133.164.41364 > 91.189.91.23.80: Flags [S], seq 1799080957, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294907400 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:45:16.328835 IP 192.168.133.1.57621 > 192.168.133.255.57621: UDP, length 44
15:45:18.803981 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.133.1 tell 192.168.133.164, length 28
15:45:18.804026 ARP, Reply 192.168.133.1 is-at 52:54:00:98:08:64, length 28
15:45:45.892037 IP 192.168.133.164.41364 > 91.189.91.23.80: Flags [S], seq 1799080957, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294915424 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:46:06.483822 IP 192.168.133.1.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: 0 [2q] PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. (45)
15:46:23.669390 IP 192.168.133.1.57621 > 192.168.133.255.57621: UDP, length 44
15:46:50.020203 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294931456 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:46:51.019807 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294931706 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:46:53.023945 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294932207 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:46:55.027790 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.133.1 tell 192.168.133.164, length 28
15:46:55.027812 ARP, Reply 192.168.133.1 is-at 52:54:00:98:08:64, length 28
15:46:57.027904 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294933208 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:47:05.043835 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294935212 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:47:21.059893 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294939216 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:47:31.002757 IP 192.168.133.1.57621 > 192.168.133.255.57621: UDP, length 44
15:47:53.123970 IP 192.168.133.164.37426 > 91.189.92.201.80: Flags [S], seq 2183110333, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4294947232 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

The IP 91.189.92.201 belongs to Canonical. However the machine is behind the proxy and cannot connect to Internet. And that was never intented. Especially on installation level.
How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already are preventing it, if it's unable to connect. If you want the connection to fail faster, then fix your router/proxy/whatever to drop the connection immediately, rather than waiting for the lengthy TCP timeout to occur. If you wish to have your firewall disallow external access, it should be dropping/closing any connection requests to non-internal addresses.

That IP is one of the round-robin addresses for the *archive.ubuntu.com* main archive server. The installer connects to it, to check for security updates, once network has been determined to be available.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. However I thought i  could disable it from installer.